# How to put make a checkbox plus 1 into a display variable Javascript

Tags: javascript

What I am trying to do is after the enter button has been pressed to add a 1 to the final display `<p>` tag.

I have gotten the checkbox to add 1 when the `qualityy` (Placeholder) Variable has been pressed but I cannot display the variable into the program as
`x.checked` is not a defined variable and
`document.getElementsByName("quality").checked` won't display anything

```
<p id="name"></p>
Very Good <input name="quality" type="checkbox" value="1">


<button onclick="buttonclickon()">Select all</button>
<button onclick="buttonclickoff()">Deselect all</button>
<button onclick="buttonenter()">Enter</button>
```

JavaScript

```
<script>
function buttonclickoff() {
  var x = document.getElementsByName("quality");
  var i;
  var qualityy = 1;

  for(i = 0; i < x.length; i++)
  {
    if( x[i].checked == true ) {  
      if (x[i].type == "checkbox") {
        x[i].checked = false;
      }
    }
  }
}

function buttonclickon() {
  var x = document.getElementsByName("quality");
  var i;
  for(i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
    if( x[i].checked == false ) {  
      if (x[i].type == "checkbox") {
        x[i].checked = true; 
      }
    }
  }
}

function buttonenter() {
  if (x[i].checked) {
    qualityy = qualityy + 1;
    
    document.getElementById("vgoodbox").innerHTML = qualityy
  }
}

</script>
```

Final display tag

```
<p id="vgoodbox">Very good: </p>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to access `x[i].checked` where neither `x` nor `i` is defined. These variable needs to defined inside the function `buttonenter`. And it seems that you want to have multiple checkboxes of similar kind, so add the `for` loop as well.

```js
function buttonclickoff() {
  var x = document.getElementsByName("quality");
  var i;

  for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {

    if (x[i].checked == true) {
      if (x[i].type == "checkbox") {
        x[i].checked = false;

      }
    }
  }
}

function buttonclickon() {
  var x = document.getElementsByName("quality");
  var i;
  for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
    if (x[i].checked == false) {
      if (x[i].type == "checkbox") {
        x[i].checked = true;

      }
    }
  }
}




function buttonenter() {
  var x = document.getElementsByName("quality");
  var i;
  var qualityy = 1;

  for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
    if (x[i].checked) {
      qualityy = qualityy + 1;
    }
  }
  document.getElementById("vgoodbox").innerHTML = "Very good: "+qualityy

}
```

```html
<p id="name"></p>
Very Good <input name="quality" type="checkbox" value="1">


<button onclick="buttonclickon()">Select all</button>
<button onclick="buttonclickoff()">Deselect all</button>
<button onclick="buttonenter()">Enter</button>

<p id="vgoodbox">Very good: </p>
```

Answer (score 0):

The main issue was you declared `x`, `i`, and `qualityy` inside of `buttonclickoff()` so they were not accessible in other functions.  The solution to this was simply to move these declarations to the top of the script.

There were other issues solved that you can see below.

```js
var x = document.getElementsByName("quality");
var i;
var qualityy = 1;
function buttonclickoff() {
  for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
    if (x[i].checked == true) {
      if (x[i].type == "checkbox") {
        x[i].checked = false;
      }
    }
  }
}

function buttonclickon() {
  var x = document.getElementsByName("quality");
  var i;
  for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
    if (x[i].checked == false) {
      if (x[i].type == "checkbox") {
        x[i].checked = true;
      }
    }
  }
}

function buttonenter() {
  for (let i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
    if (x[i].checked) {
      qualityy = qualityy + 1;
      document.getElementById("vgoodbox").innerHTML = 'Very good: ' + qualityy;
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<p id="name"></p>
Very Good <input name="quality" type="checkbox" value="1">
<button onclick="buttonclickon()">Select all</button>
<button onclick="buttonclickoff()">Deselect all</button>
<button onclick="buttonenter()">Enter</button>
<p id="vgoodbox">Very good: </p>
```

A much better way to do what you're trying to do though, is this:

```js
const btnSelect = () => {
  [...document.querySelectorAll('[name=quality]')].forEach(checkbox => checkbox.checked = true);
}
const btnDeselect = () => {
  [...document.querySelectorAll('[name=quality]')].forEach(checkbox => checkbox.checked = false);
}
const btnEnter = () => {
  const count = document.querySelectorAll('[name=quality]:checked').length;
  const { textContent } = document.querySelector('#counter');
  document.querySelector('#counter').textContent = +textContent + count;
}
```

```html
<input name='quality' type='checkbox'>
<input name='quality' type='checkbox'>
<input name='quality' type='checkbox'>

<button onclick='btnSelect()'>Select All</button>
<button onclick='btnDeselect()'>Deselect All</button>
<button onclick='btnEnter()'>Enter</button>

<span>Very good: <p id='counter'>0</p></span>
```